# Old question not clearing from label for new question

Tags: python, tkinter, label

This is my code -the old question can still be seen "under" new question. I have tried various ways to "clean" the label to make way for the new question (short of deleting the label and making a new one for every question) but nothing seems to work. Any help in this matter would be appreciated

I am new to python and I have looked at the other questions and I have tried out the solutions but nothing I have tried has worked so far. I am sure that this code could be improved but I just want a solution to the label clearing problem

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
s2=now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

global questions_asked
questions_asked=0

global score
global name
global right_answer

score =0    


def clear_text():
    e1.delete(0,'end')
    
def getName():
    name=e2.get()
    return name

def clear_sum():
    l1.config(text="")

def show_sum():
    clear_sum()
    global number1
    global number2
    number1 = random.randrange(1,12)
    number2 = random.randrange(1,12)
    l1=tk.Label(window,font=custom_font,text=("What is "+str(number1) + " x " + str(number2)+"?"))
    l1.grid(column=0,row=1, padx=10,pady=10)
    return number1, number2

def Submit():
    global questions_asked
    global score
    right_answer = number1 * number2
    answer =int(e1.get())
    if answer== right_answer:
        l2.config(text='Correct')
        score +=1
        questions_asked +=1
        clear_text()
        clear_sum()
        l1.config(text="")

 
        l3.config(text="Score  "+str(score))
        if  questions_asked >=20:
            name=e2.get()
            btn3.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
            btn1.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
            l4.config(text=("Game Over "+str(name.capitalize())+" - You got "+str(score)+" out of "+str(questions_asked)+ " correct"))
            f = open('Results.txt',"a")
            f.write('\n'+ str(s2)+ ' , ' +str(name.capitalize())+' , '+str(score))
            f.close()
    else:
        l2.config(text="Not correct, the correct answer is "+str(right_answer))
        questions_asked +=1
        clear_text()
        l1.config(text="")
      
        if questions_asked >=20:
            name=e2.get()
            btn3.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
            btn1.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
            l4.config(text=("Game Over "+str(name.capitalize())+", - You got "+str(score)+" out of "+str(questions_asked)+ " correct"))
            f = open('Results.txt',"a")
            f.write('\n'+str(s2)+ ' , ' +str(name.capitalize())+' , '+str(score))
            f.close()


window=tk.Tk()
window.title("Multiplication Practise")
window.geometry("1000x500")
window.config(bg="#A569BD")
custom_font = font.Font(size=20)

l5=tk.Label(window,font=custom_font,text=("Name"))
l5.grid(column=0,row=0, padx=10,pady=30)

e2=tk.Entry(window,font=custom_font)
e2.grid(column=1,row=0)

l1=tk.Label(window,font=custom_font,text=(""))
l1.grid(column=0,row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

e1=tk.Entry(window,font=custom_font)
e1.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=10,pady=10)

btn1=tk.Button(window,font=custom_font,text="Check Answer",bg="lightgreen",command=lambda:[Submit(),show_sum()])
btn1.grid(column=2,row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

btn3=tk.Button(window,font=custom_font,text="Submit Name",state=tk.NORMAL,bg="lightgreen",command=lambda:[show_sum(),getName()])
btn3.grid(column=2,row=0, padx=10,pady=10)

l2=tk.Label(window,font=custom_font)
l2.grid(column=1,row=2, padx=10,pady=10)
#score label
l3=tk.Label(window,font=custom_font,text=("Score  "+str(score)))l3.grid(column=0,row=3, padx=10,pady=10)
#final statement 
blank=tk.PhotoImage()
l4=tk.Label(window,image=blank, text="",font=custom_font,width=600, height=50, compound="c",bd=0, padx=0)
l4.grid(column=1,row=3,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create new label inside `show_sum()`, just update text of `l1` like `clear_sum()`:

```py
def show_sum():
    global number1
    global number2
    number1 = random.randrange(1,12)
    number2 = random.randrange(1,12)
    # update label l1
    l1.config(text=f"What is {number1} x {number2}?")
    return number1, number2
```